# Angular: Object is not a function at ApiService.saveData()

Tags: javascript, angular

**ApiService**

As you can see here `saveData()` method will hit the backend server through the given URL, but if the backend server throws any error I should display that error to the user for that I wrote the `handleError()` method and calling through the pipe operator i.e `catchError(this.handleError)` this line throwing `TypeError: Object is not a function`.

Please give any suggestion.

Code snippet:

```
import { Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
            
  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })

  export class ApiService {

  public  saveData(url,Object):Observable<any>{
      return this.http.post(url,Object).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }

    handleError(errorResponse:HttpErrorResponse){
      console.log('handleerror')
      return throwError(errorResponse.message || 'server error');
    }
    
  }
```

---

**Error**

As you can see this is the error I am finding in the console:

```
core.js:6157 ERROR TypeError: Object is not a function
    at ApiService.saveData (api.service.ts:18)
    at new-channel.component.ts:66
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:25910)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at EventEmitter_.next (Subject.js:39)
    at EventEmitter_.emit (core.js:25879)
    at ConfirmModalComponent.Passback (confirm-modal.component.ts:30)
```

Comment: It seems you're using a modal somewhere else. How is the function `saveData()` bound to the modal? Is it passed as a callback?

Comment: yes I am using modal but it's not an issue without model also it throwing same error thisis the saveData() method of ApiService  this.apiservice.saveData('urlConfig.saveAgent',this.newagentForm.value).subscribe( data=>{
          console.log('data ='+data);
        }); inside saveData() method as i describe question this line  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError)); that error

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a error function in order to use the catchError method.

See here:

[enter link description here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError)

```
.pipe(catchError(err => this.yourErrorHandler(err)))
```

Comment: Thank you,as you said i added this line .pipe(catchError(err =>this.handleError(err))); but it still throwing same error

Comment: `.pipe(catchError(err => this.handleError(err)))` would be correct

Answer (score 0):

I believe Object is the reserved syntax. Try renaming it something else. If it doesnt work then please show how you are calling it.

Comment: this component-level code here i am calling saveData() method of ApiService  this.apiservice.saveData('urlConfig.saveAgent',this.newagentForm.value).subscribe( data=>{
          console.log('data ='+data);
        });

Comment: Can you please rename "Object" to something like "postBody". I doubt the use of "Object" variable as it is reserved by JavaScript.

public  saveData(url, postBody)